# Why can't I copy text from the Ubuntu Terminal?

Tags: command-line, clipboard, text

This is really weird. I can't copy anything from the terminal. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> command and `Edit->Copy` does nothing, no matter how much or little text I have selected. What ever was on my clipboard before the command is still there after.

Why can't I copy text from the Terminal?

Pasting into the terminal works just fine

Comment: Works fine for me... How do you paste? Middle click or with `Ctrl`+`V`?

Comment: Pasting into the terminal works just fine, added that to the question. What's the difference between pasting normally or using Middle click?

Comment: @Codemonkey Middle click pastes whatever text is selected at the moment. Ctrl-V uses the clipboard (ie. what is copied using Copy or Ctrl-C). Some clipboard managers synchronize both clipboards, but they are usually separate.

Comment: In that case, middle click works as it should, but no text gets added to the clipboard on copy

Comment: What's your Linux distribution version and kernel version?
I guess your kernel version is too old, and does not match your distribution.

Answer (score 3):

you can, But you have to go into the settings.

Edit -> Keyboard shortcuts -> *find copy and past commands* -> Click to alter and enter new combo "ctrl+x, v, c, etc..."

Comment: Why would changing the copy key combo help if copying doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In most Windows environments (not sure for others), you will have to highlight the text and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to copy the text. You can then simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> (paste) it e everywhere. Maybe that works on your (specific?) Ubuntu terminal as well.

Answer (score 0):

I do a  `>copy.txt` to output my screen result.
Like `aplay -l > text.txt` give me a text.txt where I can open up in gedit by clicking on the file everything is formatted nicely. Here you can Ctrl-C then Ctrl-V just like Windows.

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 0: ALC888 Analog [ALC888 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 1: ALC888 Digital [ALC888 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```